# Uploading image from razor view without @HTML.BeginForm

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC3 application. My main view have only one `@HTML.BeginForm` where is almost all my markup. Partially this is because I want to submit all the information at once, I have text, images and so on, and want when the user click "Save" all this to be saved.

However when I deal with images I want the user to be able to add/remove images as many times as he wants, but the information that will be permanently saved should be the one that I get on form submit. That's why I seek a way to upload images to the server and show them in my view, but I wonder if this is possible without using forms.

I guess some sort of Ajax maybe. For now I have this :

```
<span class="document-image-frame">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
        @Html.ActionLink("Upload Picture", "UploadPicture", new { documentID = Model[0].DocumentId })
```

But it was a week ago when I last was working on this and now my controller which is declared like this:

```
public ActionResult UploadPicture(HttpPostedFileBase file, FormCollection collection)
        {
         //code goes here...
```

is throwing this exception :

```
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
```

But I think this is because this code left from when I was using separate `@Html.BeginForm` for the images.

Is there some MVC3 way of doing this or some AJAX helper I could use to make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see below how you can approach to your solution.

**Step 1: First add/upload image on server**

- Create two action method one to save the data and second to upload  the image. For e.g. **SaveInformation** to save data and **UploadPicture** to upload image.
- Create a partial view for the code to display image uploaded by user.
- In your main view where you have all your html, create a form tag and assign the action attribute to call **SaveInformation** action method.
- Create a JQuery function which you need to call on image upload button. In this function first you need to **change the action attribute** dynamically from **SaveInformation** to **UploadImage** so that you can upload your image on server. You can accomplish this task by writing code something like this:

  `var action = "/ControllerName/UploadImage";`

  $("#IdOfYourFormTag").attr("action", action);
- Now in the same function write code for a JQuery ajax call and submit your form which will now hit the action method UploadImage and will upload image on server. In the same action method UploadImage now update your partial view by passing it new image path and return it as the response of your ajax call and in your JQuery method update your partial view by handling Ajax call Success event.

Also Please add **enctype = "multipart/form-data** peace of code in your form tag without this you wont be able send your image from view to controller and in your UploadImage action method add one parameter **HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload** also to get the file.

**Step 2: Finally Save image path permanently on server**

- Create a property with the name as **ImagePath** which will store the path of image.
- Create a hidden filed in your partial view which you created  to display your image and bind it with the ImagePath property. The idea behind to put the hidden field here is that it will also be updated with new image path at the time of uploading the image.
- Now when you submit your form to update the rest of information then also get the path of image from this hidden field and save it in database.

That's all. Hope this will help you.

If you still have any question then please feel free to ask me.

#### Edit:

First of all I want to tell you that I have not used Ajax call as with **ajax call we will get null value instead of file which we need to upload because of some security purpose.** Fileupload works with normal post method or we have to use some jquery plugins.

Ok, Now first Look at **Model :**

In Model I have created a property to hold file path:

```
public class InformationModel
{       
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    // Your rest of properties
}
```

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveInformation", "Home",null, FormMethod.Post, new { id =   "SaveInformation", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{      
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ImagePath)
<input type="file" name="FileUpload" id="FileUpload" />                   
<input type="button" id="Upload" name="Upload" value="Upload" />    
<input type="submit" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> 
}
```

In the above code I have just create a form having one file upload control and two buttons one for uploading the file and second to submit the entire form and a hidden field to hold the file path.

To just upload the file I have written the code in jquery which is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input#Upload").click(function () {
        $("#SaveInformation").attr("action", "/Home/UploadImage");
        $("#SaveInformation").submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

The above piece of code will just simply change the form action method from hitting to **UploadImage** action method instead of **SaveInformation** action and will submit the form.

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadImage(InformationModel model, HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload)
    {
        //First write your code here to Upload the image
        string path = "/YourVirtualDirectoryPath/"; 
        path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(path), FileUpload.FileName);
        FileUpload.SaveAs(path);

        model.ImagePath = path;
        //If you need to maintain the entire model you can do it like this or you can just assign the file path to the temp session 
        //and redirect to SaveInformation get method.
        this.TempData["FilePath"] = model;
        return RedirectToAction("SaveInformation");
    }
```

In the above method I have just uploaded the file and assigned the image path to ImagePath property and assigned the model to temp session data so that model values can be preserved and redirected the control to "SaveInformation" get method which is I am using to load our main form.

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SaveInformation()
    {
        InformationModel model = null;
        if (this.TempData["FilePath"] != null)
        {
            model = (InformationModel)TempData["FilePath"];
        }
        else
        {
            model = new InformationModel();
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Above action method contains a simple logic that if the request is coming from UploadImage action method then just fill the model from temp session data or create new instance and load the view.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveInformation(InformationModel model)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("SaveInformation");
    }
```

Above method is just to save all the values. When you click on Submit button then you will see that **model.ImagePath** contains the file path which you need to save along with rest of information.

Hope now you will get the solution of your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I've implemented the back end pretty much the same way that you suggested but to be honest I have very poor knowledge about jQuery and all AJAX magics one could do. I understand the logic order but don't know how exactly to implement the jQuery part.

Comment: No Problem Leron, I will write you the code here as soon as I will finish my current assigned task.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is very kind of you!